# Editing content that is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to edit a 3 model on has_many. My question is about the controller and how can I access the information

I have the following model

```
Customer          Book           Book_Manager
id                id             id
first             description    customer_id
last                             book_id
email                            visible
password
```

The relationship his has follow

```
Customer
  has_many book_managers
  has_many books :through -> book_managers
Book
  has_many book_managers
  has_many customer :through -> book_managers
Book_managers
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :book
```

When a customer wants to edit the content, i want to be the latest one to be shown if any exist. The query i have at the moment doesn't seem to handle an empty case and not sure how to do it.

```
@book = current_customer.books.order("created_at DESC").first
```

How should i declare it in a def edit of the customercontroller??

Update: I want to be able to see my data, unfoturnotly it doesn't seem to work here my

```
customer controller

        def create
        @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
            @book = @customer.books.build(params[:book])
        if @customer.save
        cookies[:auth_token] = @customer.auth_token
        redirect_to @customer, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end
    def edit
        @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
        if current_customer.books.length > 0
           @book = current_customer.books.order("created_at DESC").first
        else
           #Nor books were found, so create one that has the proper relationship to current_customer
           @book = current_customer.books.build
        end
        end
```

I am rendering a partial from the book folder, should my create option be in the customer Controller or in bookControllers

Update: using customerController has my main create, when creating its say missing actions in books controller should i have more action in the book controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is a simple check in the controller to see if any books exist. If one does not exists then create a new one.

```
#Check if the books array contains anything. There are several ways to do this
if current_customer.books.length > 0
   @book = current_customer.books.order("created_at DESC").first
else
   #Nor books were found, so create one that has the proper relationship to current_customer
   @book = current_customer.books.build
end
```

Comment: Would build create a new instance?

Comment: For what it's worth, Array#empty? is a clean way to check if an array has any elements.

Comment: Yes, it would create a new instance. @PeteSchlette, that's a good one, I had forgotten about that. +1.

Comment: Thanks one more question how would i set my create command in the customer controller i am assuming. I have the following but doesn't work @book = current_customer.books.build(params[:book])

Comment: I was under the understanding that you wanted a new book instance, so you wouldn't actually have any :book parameters to work with.

Comment: Originally its empty, if the customer create a new book description then it build the new books, if not then it does your thing which works, but i dont see when coming back, the new book instance in my field, i don't know if its created properly

Comment: My main questions is because i am using a partial, rending the form from book/form.html.erb. Should my create and edit be in the customer controller or in the book controller?

Comment: It should be in whichever controller you are calling the action from. If this is in more than one place you might want to factor it out into your model, probably your customer model.

Comment: okay so it would be in my customer controller, but doesn't seem to create a new book instance or i don't see any reason why, my customer controller is there

Comment: How are you verifying the existence of the book?

Comment: If it show in my text field :S, not sure how else, i am using linux, ubuntu if you know a software that allow to verify it was created

Comment: You need to read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html